# How to count the strings in a vector?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set as I've shown below:

```
df_A <- tribble(
      ~shop_name,      ~id,      
        "A",         "1, 4, 3", 
        "B",         "4, 6",   
        "C",         "3, 5",   
        "D",         "6, 2, 3", 
)
```

Now, I want to group the data by each unique id which in the vector, and then count them accordingly. Do you think it is doable? How can I manipulate the data to get my desired data?

```
desired <- tribble(
  ~id,   ~counted_id,      
  "1",      1, 
  "2",      1,   
  "3",      3,   
  "4",      2, 
  "5",      1,   
  "6",      2, 
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach with `separate_rows` from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df_A %>%
  separate_rows(id, sep=", ") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(counted_id = n())
## A tibble: 6 x 2
#  id    counted_id
#  <chr>      <int>
#1 1              1
#2 2              1
#3 3              3
#4 4              2
#5 5              1
#6 6              2
```

Comment: you can also use `count()`, i.e `df_A %>% separate_rows(id) %>% group_by(id) %>% count()`

Comment: It worked great! Thanks a lot for your quick response. @Ian Campbell

Comment: You can do `count(name = 'counted_id')`

Comment: @Sotos and even get rid of the `group_by(id)`: df_A %>% separate_rows(id) %>% count(id, name = "counted_id")

Comment: I think that sometimes simplifying the answer too far takes the learning out of it. But That's pretty slick Dominik

Comment: @Ian Campbell that's certainly true.

Answer (score 5):

You can do with by splitting your string on ", " and table:

```
as.data.frame(table(unlist(strsplit(df_A$id,", "))))

  Var1 Freq
1    1    1
2    2    1
3    3    3
4    4    2
5    5    1
6    6    2
```

Answer (score 4):

Minimalist `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
df_A %>% 
  separate_rows(id) %>% 
  count(id, name = "counted_id")


# A tibble: 6 x 2
  id    counted_id
  <chr>      <int>
1 1              1
2 2              1
3 3              3
4 4              2
5 5              1
6 6              2
```

Answer (score 3):

In base R

```
id_vector <- unlist(strsplit(df_A$id, ", "))
data.frame(table(id_vector))

#   id_vector Freq
# 1         1    1
# 2         2    1
# 3         3    3
# 4         4    2
# 5         5    1
# 6         6    2
```

Using `stringr::str_count()`:

```
ids <- as.character(1:7)
data.frame(
  id = ids,
  counted_id = sapply(ids, function(x) sum(str_count(df_A$id, x)))
)

#   id counted_id
# 1  1          1
# 2  2          1
# 3  3          3
# 4  4          2
# 5  5          1
# 6  6          2
# 7  7          0
```